# django admin filter change_list fields according to the user group

Tags: python, django

I'm using django admin to generate the form to include some data in the database but i need to hide certain form fields according to the user group.

So, let's say I've a Model such as:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    description = models.CharField(...)
    approved = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('y', 'yes'), ('n','no'), ('w', 'waiting'))
```

Where I want the user of the group "basic" see in the form only "name" and "description" and the user of the group "advanced" see also the "approved" status.

Do I need to use a customized template?
Whether you say yes or no please help me referring to some docs or with an example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override get_form method in ProductAdmin class. From original method:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    ....
    ....
    defaults = {
        "form": self.form,
        "fields": fields,
        "exclude": exclude,
        "formfield_callback": curry(self.formfield_for_dbfield, request=request),
    }
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    ...
```

So you can dynamically change either self.form or fields or exclude

Comment: Thank you for this report, I'm going to find out more on the doc!

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an `__init__` method in your form. Here, you will have access to the user object , if present. based on team membership, you can customize your form.

Some snippets:

function signature and getting the user object:

```
 def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):       
        self.user=None
        if kwargs:
            self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
```

Function to check if user is in group:

```
def is_user_in_group(user,group_name):
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).count() == 1
```

Snippet to make a field hidden -- this will go in your `__init__` method:

```
self.fields['some_field_to_hide'].widget = widgets.HiddenInput
```

I am going from memory here, so please excuse typos.

Comment: thnx, very helpful explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide specific fields only, while still allowing change, the minimal solution might be to add your admin users to a new group and reduce fields based on group membership. Here is a reusable class to drop-in:

```
class ExternalAdminModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    external_admin_group = 'external_admin'
    hidden_fields = []

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.fields = [field.name for field in Node._meta.local_concrete_fields if not field.name == 'id']

        if Group.objects.get(name=self.external_admin_group).user_set.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            for field_name in self.hidden_fields:
                self.fields.remove(field_name)

        return super(ExternalAdminModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

You only need to set the hidden fields property for your models:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyAdmin(ExternalAdminModelAdmin):
    hidden_fields = ['sensitive_field']
```